# unable to Post data to a login form using urllib python v3.2.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

```
    import urllib.parse
    import urllib.request
    import time
    def __init__(self, parent= None):

    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    username = 'name'

    password = 'pass'
    while True:
            try:
                page=urllib.request.urlopen('http://10.100.56.55:8090/httpclient.html','&username='+username+'@da-iict.org&password='+password+'&btnSubmit=Login')
                the_page=page.read()
```

I have been trying to get this piece of code to work. the alternative in python 2 works just fine but in python v3.2 I get the error " **POST data should be bytes or an iterable number of bytes**

Comment: I have been trying to get this piece of code to work. the alternative in python 2 works just fine but in python v3.2 I get the error " **POST data should be bytes or an iterable number of bytes**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import time

username = 'name'
password = 'pass'

tm = 60

while True:
    url = "http://10.100.56.55:8090/httpclient.html"
    values = {'username': username, 'password': password, 'btnSubmit':'Login'}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    binary_data = data.encode('ascii')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, binary_data)
    urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

In Python3 they have changed it so that the data needs to be binary, thus you have to encode it first. ASCII is fine if your username/password does not include any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I understand the problem now. But still the code dosen't seem to be working. It says error in page=urllib.request.urlopen(url,binary_data).  http.client.BADSTATUSLINE : ''

Comment: You mean by typing in as http://10.100.56.55:8090/httpclient.html?username=name&...  ??

Comment: yes. The error basically means that the response is received, but the http status code cannot be parsed (it's empty).

Comment: You may also try to disable your firewall.

Comment: trying to figure out the way it should work in the browser. I guess firewall isn;t the problem