# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack, PoolManager request

Tags: python, django, urllib3

The following code in `utils.py`

```
manager = PoolManager()
data = json.dumps(dict) #takes in a python dictionary of json
manager.request("POST", "https://myurlthattakesjson", data)
```

Gives me `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` when the server is run. Does this most likely mean that the JSON is incorrect or something else?

Comment: How does `dict` look like?

Comment: At what line does it give you the error? Could you post your entire stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Json data needs to be URLencoded for it to be POST (or GET) safe.

```
# import parser
import urllib.parse

manager = PoolManager()

# stringify your data
data = json.dumps(dict) #takes in a python dictionary of json

# base64 encode your data string
encdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)    

manager.request("POST", "https://myurlthattakesjson", encdata)
```

I believe in python3 they made some changes that the data needs to be binary. See [unable to Post data to a login form using urllib python v3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188561/unable-to-post-data-to-a-login-form-using-urllib-python-v3-2-1)